# Does GridSearchCV not save the best parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search, gridsearchcv

So I tuned the hyperparameters using `GridSearchCV`, fitted the model to the data, and then used `best_params_`. I'm just curious why `GridSearchCV` takes too long to run `best_params_`, unlike RandomSearchCV where it instantly gives answers. The time it takes for GridSearchCV to give the `best_params_` is similar to the time it takes for GridSearchCV to tune hyperparameters, and fit the model to the data. It's as if it's doing it all over again when it has done so already. Is this the case? If not, what's taking it so long when it should have saved the best_params_ when I ran GridSearchCV the first time?

Comment: I have never had this problem.  `best_params_` gets populated when fitting, in the `BaseSearchCV` class (which `GridSearchCV` inherits from), so indeed it should take basically 0 time to retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, please try the following code

CELL1:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

CELL2:

```
%%time
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':np.linspace(0.1,100,1000)}
svc = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

CELL3:

```
%%time
clf.best_params_
```

Wall time of CELL2 will be about 7-9 seconds.
Wall time of CELL3 will be 0ns. ( instantaneous )

This is because `best_params_` is an argument of GridSearchCV. It is however only created (and accessible) once you run .fit method.